# Info Parsing (JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, phantomjs

I am wondering how to use Javascript to Parse a text into an Array,

Here is the Text I wish to Parse : http://data.bter.com/api/1/pairs

and here is the code I am using :

```
var mycont = page.content;
var arr = JSON.parse(mycont);
console.log(arr[0].name);
```

Sadly I am getting :

> SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string

Any Ideas what I am doing wrong ? if this is not Json then any idea how to parse it ?

Comment: That usually means the string is not valid json. you either need to manipulate the string in a way that results in valid json, or have the server return valid json in the first place.

Comment: I dont have access to the Server, What I need to do in that case ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the string in the question?

Comment: How are you populating `page.content`?

Comment: page.content is a function inside phantomJS that saves all source Code inside page to variable

Comment: @KevinB check the string here : http://data.bter.com/api/1/pairs

Comment: This is not valid json! Read more about it here http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: @gat I need a solution to put data in an array, I dont care if its json or not.

Comment: @gat — It looks valid to me. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: If you just need to convert it to an array, remove the opening and closing square brackets and then 'var array = string.split(',');'

Comment: @victory i can't(won't) get to that url, that's why i asked for a sample.

Comment: @gat I need a more professional way, also that will add double quotation between values which I don't need

Comment: @kevin B here you go : ["btc_cny","ltc_cny","bqc_cny","btb_cny",..... ,"yac_ltc"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`page.content` gives you an HTML document view of the JSON.

```
<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
["btc_cny","ltc_cny","bqc_cny","btb_cny","btq_cny","cent_cny","cmc_cny","cnc_cny
etc etc
```

Use `page.plainText` instead.

(The moral of the story is, when your JSON isn't parsing, `console.log` the data you are actually trying to parse instead of looking at the URL you are getting it from in a browser).